# How to add Vaadin to an existing Spring Boot project and make Vaadin actually start/build my frontend plus routes?

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, frontend, vaadin

Hellо аll,

I have a Spring-boot project that currently doesn't have any frontend/UI.

[Here](https://github.com/Jmorkcho/CinemaApp) is the public repository that you can find all of the code. Notice that it won't run without an SQL server set up in application.properties file/environment variables.

[Here](https://github.com/Jmorkcho/WebAppUniProject-Vaadin) is another repo of a project that actually uses/starts Vaadin and builds the frontend.

I tried adding Vaadin dependencies into my POM.xml.

Here are the dependencies I added:

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.0.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <!--adding vaadin!-->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <!-- declare the latest Vaadin version
                     as a property or directly here -->
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!--adding vaadin!-->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- adding vaadin!-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>24.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
```

I also added a simple class LoginView in order to try whether the route and ui works:

```
@Route(value = "login")
@PageTitle("Login | University Project")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private final LoginForm login = new LoginForm();

    public LoginView() {

        addClassName("login-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        getStyle().set("background", "869fcb");
        Button login1 = new Button("Login");
        login.setAction("login");

        //////////////
        //HorizontalLayout back = new HorizontalLayout();
        //back.setSizeFull();
        //back.getStyle().set("background","red");
        //////////////
        add(toggleButtonTheme, new H1("University Project"), login, registrationButton);
    }

    Button toggleButtonTheme = new Button("Toggle dark theme", click -> {
        ThemeList themeList = UI.getCurrent().getElement().getThemeList(); // (1)

        if (themeList.contains(Lumo.DARK)) { // (2)
            themeList.remove(Lumo.DARK);
        } else {
            themeList.add(Lumo.DARK);
        }
    });

    Button registrationButton = new Button("Register", event -> UI.getCurrent().navigate("registration"));

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        // inform the user about an authentication error
        if (beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
                .getQueryParameters()
                .getParameters()
                .containsKey("error")) {
            login.setError(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Then "localhost:8888/login" page returns the "Whitelabel Error Page"...

I tried running "mvn clean install"/"mvn package"/"mvn deploy"/etc. - all the maven commands and then running the application from the jar itself - Vaadin doesn't start as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxy2JgqqKDU).

I also tried to add "vaadin:build-frontend" and every other vaadin plugin command before my Run configuration, yet it doesn't start Vaadin.

Expected outcome/run log:

```
##excluded some log events here##

2023-05-18 10:34:24.155  INFO 20288 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration   : 
Vaadin is running in DEVELOPMENT mode - do not use for production deployments.
2023-05-18 10:34:24.212  INFO 20288 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-05-18 10:34:24.225  INFO 20288 --- [  restartedMain] com.uniproject.application.Application   : Started Application in 8.524 seconds (JVM running for 9.355)
2023-05-18 10:34:24.230  INFO 20288 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Starting Vite
2023-05-18 10:34:24.853  INFO 20288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-18 10:34:24.853  INFO 20288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-18 10:34:24.855  INFO 20288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms

------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
2023-05-18 10:34:33.325  INFO 20288 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Running Vite to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2023-05-18 10:34:36.774  INFO 20288 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-05-18 10:34:36.774  INFO 20288 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   VITE v3.2.4  ready in 3377 ms

----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------

2023-05-18 10:34:36.774  INFO 20288 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Started Vite. Time: 12544ms
2023-05-18 10:34:36.774  INFO 20288 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-05-18 10:34:36.775  INFO 20288 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:61319/VAADIN/
2023-05-18 10:34:38.045  INFO 20288 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-05-18 10:34:38.046  INFO 20288 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [TypeScript] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Actual outcome/run log:

```
##excluded some event logs here##

2023-05-18 10:35:50.078  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-05-18 10:35:50.078  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-05-18 10:35:51.601  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-18 10:35:51.791  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 174 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-18 10:35:52.973  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2023-05-18 10:35:52.985  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-18 10:35:52.985  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2023-05-18 10:35:53.139  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-18 10:35:53.139  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3060 ms
2023-05-18 10:35:53.389  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-18 10:35:53.459  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2023-05-18 10:35:53.639  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-05-18 10:35:53.823  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-18 10:35:54.118  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-18 10:35:54.158  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
2023-05-18 10:35:55.117  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-18 10:35:55.127  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-18 10:35:56.214  WARN 18152 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-05-18 10:35:56.476  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2023-05-18 10:35:56.495  WARN 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2023-05-18 10:35:56.795  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
2023-05-18 10:35:57.445  INFO 18152 --- [  restartedMain] com.finals.cinema.CinemaApplication      : Started CinemaApplication in 8.049 seconds (JVM running for 9.291)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your pom looks totally off. Download a project from start.vaadin.com and check the difference, especially the maven plugin which you have added as Dependency instead of using it as plugin.

Comment: Yes, it is a different pom.xml file since the project was not based off on Vaadin initially.
I searched and found which dependencies to add by going to [Vaadin's official documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/spring/spring-boot), but adding those dependencies did nothing to the run behaviour of the project.

Comment: Please post what you have did and did not work. Or update your repo.

Comment: I pushed to my repository and commented on @Marco C's comment thread what is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin 24 requires Spring Boot 3.x, but it seems your project is using 2.4.
You should either upgrade Spring Boot, or use Vaadin 23.3

Comment: Using Vaadin version 23.3 doesn't do anything - the project runs without frontend again.

Using Spring boot 3.0.0 results in the following error: "java: package javax.servlet.http does not exist". Then I have to add javax.servlet-api 4.0.1 to my pom.

Then I get the error that "import javax.persistence.*" cannot be found.
Then I add hibernate-jpa-2.1-api to fix the persistence error and I finally get 
"java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present" error.

Comment: Vaadin 24 requires Java 17, Spring Boot 3, and Jakarta EE 10. So your project should be updated accordingly or you have to use Vaadin 23.3
Vaadin 23.3 may not work because the spring boot version used in the repository you shared is quite old, you should proabably move to Spring Boot 2.7

Comment: Updated all of the dependencies in pom file.
Java is 17, Spring boot is 3.0.5, jakarta.servlet-api is 5.0.0, jakartaee-api is 10.0-M1.
Still same error.

Comment: You are still importing dependencies that references "javax.*" API.
For example, in you pom you have `vaadin-spring` at version `3.2.1` that you can remove as it is already defined by `vaadin-spring-boot-starter`.
But there may be other dependencies to fix

Comment: It seems `springfox-swagger2` does not support Spring Boot 3 and Jakarta EE 10

Comment: I removed every import/dependency for javax and I pushed to my repository.
Right now, the error is _Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start_ and when I found answers in SO, they were saying that I need at least javax.servlet-api version 3.1 ...

Comment: The cause of the error and the solution is on the logs

    Found app shell configuration annotations in non 'AppShellConfigurator' classes.
    Please create a custom class implementing 'AppShellConfigurator' and move the 
    following annotations to it:
        - @Theme from com.finals.cinema.CinemaApplication

But then you there's another error because in your repo the theme `flowcrmtutorial` is not present in the `frontend/themes` folder

(Sorry, I was unable to correctly format the comment)

Comment: Thank you for the consistent support, @Marco!
I finally got it up and running. Created the flowcrmtutorial theme and made my main class "CinemaApplication" to implement the AppShellConfigurator interface!